# MVC 3, View Model for user registration process. Password validation not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, view, model, passwords

I am trying to create a user registration page using MVC 3, so that I can better understand the process of how it works, what's going on behind the scenes etc. I am running into some issues when trying to use `[Compare]` to check to see that the user entered the same password twice.

I tried adding the `ComparePassword` field to my user model first, and found that would not work the way I wanted as I did not have the field in the database, so the obvious answer was to create a View Model using the same information including the `ComparePassword` field.

So I now have created a `User` model and a `RegistrationViewModel`, however it appears that the `[Compare]` on the password is not returning anything, for instance no matter what I put in the two boxes, when I click create it gives no error, which seems to me to mean it was successfully validated.

I am not sure what I am doing or not doing to make this work properly. I have tried updating the `jQuery.Validate` to the newest version as there were some bugs reported in older version, this has not helped my efforts.

Below is all of the code that I am working with.

```
    public class RegistrationViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Display(Name = "User Name")]
        [RegularExpression(@"(\S)+", ErrorMessage = " White Space is not allowed in User Names")]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public String Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public String firstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public String lastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public String email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public String password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Re-enter Password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Passwords do not match.")]
        public String comparePassword { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the CompareAttribute case-sensitive? I see your referencing "Password" in the attribute but your property is declared as "password".

Comment: I tend to over-think things and I was missing the obvious case sensitivity. Thank you for helping in a polite and constructive manner, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @sec_goat Your welcome :) Sometimes all you need is a fresh set of eyes!